# Configuring Office365 for Events

Tags: office365, office365api

I am using Office365 REST APIs. I am following below mentioned link for the same:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api

I am going through Notification API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations

I am successfullly able to subscribe to the events using REST API refering to the above mentioned linked.

I was wandering whether there is any configuiration on UI for webhooks/notification to Subscribe to changes in my mail, calendar, contacts, or tasks.

If there is any I would like to know the steps of configuration or using REST API is the only way of subscribing to any such events for Office365.

Thanks,
Purva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Notification API is provided on the API level and there is no corresponding feature in Outlook and Exchange.